# Using Windows clipboard in Delphi console program

Tags: delphi, console-application, clipboard

I am trying to use the (Windows) clipboard in a Delphi console program, but when I try to compile I get the message

"[dcc32 Fatal Error] Clipboard_Project.dpr(6): F2613 Unit 'Clpbrd' not found."

The code looks like this:

```
program Clipboard_Project;

{$R *.res}

uses
    System.SysUtils, Clpbrd;

var
    s: String;

begin
  try
        s := Clipboard.AsText;
        writeln(s);
        readln;
  except
     on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I can imagine that it's something simple and obvious, but I can't find it! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The correct unit name is ClipBrd, not ClpBrd.  Make sure Delphi can find ClipBrd.Dcu - the compiled version of ClipBrd.Pas - from your project path settings.

Comment: And you probably need to use `Vcl.ClipBrd` because a default console app won't search the `Vcl` namespace, IIRC.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, ClpBrd is clearly a typo. I was even getting the problem when it was spelled correctly, so the real issue was using Vcl. in front. That solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for correction of this question, it should be used in the uses clause `Vcl.ClipBrd` correctly and not Clpbrd as incorrectly typed.